# How to invoke a function with specific parameter types

Tags: julia

Say I have a struct **Point** like this one:

```
struct Point
    x::Real
    y::Real
end
```

I want to create a new "*" operator, so I tried:

```
function *(p1::Point, k::Real)::Point
    return Punto(p1.x * k, p1.y * k)
end
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
julia> println(Point(5, 6) * 2)
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching *(::Int64, ::Int64)
You may have intended to import Base.:*
Closest candidates are:
    *(::Point, ::Real) at ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] *(p1::Point, k::Int64)
 [2] top-level scope
```

It seems that, now that I have created a new method for '*', I cannot use the primitive ones inside it. I suppose that I have to invoke them specifically.

I learned that I can invoke an specific version of a method with @invoke:

```
julia> p1 = Point(5, 6)
julia> Base.@invoke *(p1.x::Real, 6::Real)
julia> 30
```

So, it should be as simple as:

```
function *(p1::Punto, k::Real)::Punto
    return Point(
            Base.@invoke *(p1.x::Real, k::Real),
            Base.@invoke *(p1.y::Real, k::Real))
end
```

But no, unfortunately it does not work either:

```
julia> println(Point(5, 6) * 7)
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching var"@invoke"(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::Expr, ::Expr)
Closest candidates are:
  var"@invoke"(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::Any) at reflection.jl:1778
  in expression starting at REPL[19]:2
```

So, it seems to work outside a function, but not inside. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define `*()` you hide the function `Base.*`. The conventional way is not to *overwrite* functions, but to *extend* them:

```
function Base.:*(p1::Point, k::Real)
    return Point(p1.x * k, p1.y * k)
end
```

Now you can call `Point(5, 6) * 7` as normal, no need for `invoke`.

I would also suggest to not use abstractly typed field names. Either select a concrete field type for `Point` (like `Float64`), or make it into parametric type:

```
struct Point{T<:Real}
    x::T
    y::T
end
```

If you don't do this, your code will be unnecessarily slow (on the order of 100x slower).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand that extending functions is the correct way. But let's assume that, for whatever reason, I wan to overwrite them. How would I use invoke in that case?

Comment: I don't know, I have never had any cause to do this, and I am curious why you would want to. Overwriting a basic operation like multiplication is likely to cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: I guess you could write: `*(p1::Point, k::Real) = Point(Base.:(*)(p1.x, k), Base.:(*)(p1.y, k))`. Using `invoke` should not work, I believe, since that is for calling specific methods of a function, but by defining an entirely new function `*`, the old multiplication function is gone, and can only be accessed by qualifying the call with `Base.:(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Julia will generate a specialized function based on the arguments. So if you write the function without any arguments, it should call `*(Int64, Int64)` because it is the narrowest definition possible. If you are willing to change this a little you may be interested in [conversion and promotion](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/conversion-and-promotion/#conversion-and-promotion) in Julia.

`invoke` and `@invoke` needs the function to be invoked as the first argument. Notice that the function is missing inside your redefinition.

You can also use `invoke` as a function:

```
ff(a::Real, b::Real) = a*a + b
invoke(ff, Tuple{Real, Real}, x, y)
```

EDIT:

Now that the question has changed a little, I'll go with @DNF answer:

```
struct Point{T<:Real}
       x::T
       y::T
end
Base.:*(p::Point, k) = Point(p.x * k, p.y * k)
Base.:*(k, p::Point) = p*k # implement commutativity :)

p1 = Point(5, 6)

julia> p1 * 5
Point{Int64}(25, 30)

julia> 5 * p1
Point{Int64}(25, 30)

julia> 5.0 * p1
Point{Float64}(25.0, 30.0)
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is obvious that I need to give more insight details. Also, the @invoke macro missing the function name is another typo. I've now edited the question with these aspects in mind.